# Creating multilevel-WBS level lists in excel? Task 1.1, Sub task 1.1.1

Tags: excel, project-management

Is there a way of creating multilevel-WBS level lists in excel? For example, Avtivity 1, Then Task 1.1, Sub task 1.1.1, 1.1.2, 1.1.3 and so on until we get to Activity 2. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

There is a free package available online as [Vertex/work-breakdown-structure](https://www.vertex42.com/Files/download2/themed.php?file=work-breakdown-structure.xlsx).

You can use multilevel-WBS level lists in it as you can see in the
[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CEwlQ.jpg)
[image]